# have unicode characters in url

Tags: python, django

for example in this url:

```
(r'^company/لیست-مقالات/$','CompanyHub.views.docList')
```

in `لیست مقالات` part I have unicode characters but I get this error:

```
Caught UnicodeDecodeError while rendering: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd9 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: See here: http://bit.ly/unipain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put a `u` in front of `r` before the string, or wrap it in the unicode method:

See [this](http://www.amk.ca/python/howto/unicode) for more info.

> Unicode strings are much like strings, but are specified in the syntax
>   using a preceding 'u' character: u'abc', u"def".

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html

Answer (score 1):

First, to use non-ASCII characters in a string literal in Python you need to specify a character encoding at the top of your source file e.g.:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Second, if you [pass a Unicode string to django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/) it usually does the right thing by itself. In this case it should convert all non-ASCII characters in the URL. If it is not then you could call [`django.utils.encoding.iri_to_uri()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/) explicitly.